# Alternative to standard Sony PCM D50 windsock?

Tags: sony, pcm, wind

Has anyone with a Sony PCM D50 had better luck with an alternative or custom windsock?

Cutting out wind from recordings on near-windless days is getting a bit tired..

It's great otherwise, so I'm not really complaining

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Rode Dead Kitten](http://www.rodemic.com/accessory.php?product=DeadKitten) is meant to be a good alternative, not used one on a D50 but works well with an Nt-4

Thew's Reviews posted a comparison of the Dead Kitten & the standard Sony one [here](http://www.thewsreviews.com/2009/09/comparison-sony-adpcm1-and-rde-dead.html)

Comment: Cheers Andrew-- it's a good comparison. From his recorded examples it sounds like the Rode reduced a considerable amount more wind noise but at a cost to some top end.. which might start to then make the pre-amp noise a problem.. I'm going to give the dead kitten a go this week anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@James The D50 is really not of much use without a windscreen unless its statically positioned and inside. Personally I had a hard time justifying the high price tag of Sony's own and tried alternatives. I found GigWig's Eliminator a great buy, it eliminates the wind a great deal, it's cheap, doesn't shed a lot and it actually stays in place on top of the recorder.

[GigWig Windscreens](http://stores.ebay.com/GigWig-Windscreens)

Comment: yeah I always use one, but it's not great hence me looking for an alternative. I'll take a look at GigWig. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I buy from [Red Head Windscreens](http://www.redheadwindscreens.com/products/) they work out a lot cheaper for me.

Comment: I've got the standard Sony one, but I've heard good things from multiple people about the Red Head screens.

Comment: Thanks Ade ---  have you compared them to the standard ones or just gone red head from the start?

Comment: Red head from the start, I priced up the Roycote one and for me in the UK it was £30. The Red Head worked out around £20 (delivered from the USA). A few others on this site recommended it so I took the plunge and it works great. If its something stupid like 70 mph winds you will still get some wind noise but windsheilds can only do so much.

Answer (score 1):

my wife made one for me out of cheesecloth and fuzzy yarn.  Works great and looks awesome.  :)